# Как поймать данный Event на JS?

Tags: javascript

есть родительский див. В нем через через ajax добавляются дочерние дивы. Как поймать события когда в Parent добавляется новый дочерний элемент и как получить этот дочерний элемент в переменную. А когда добавиться новый див то перезаписать переменную и в ней будет новый последний див

Comment: Как вариант перехватить ajax и полученный ответ передать своей функции, которая будет уже делать все что захочешь.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver